# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type using typescript?

Tags: typescript

i am trying to fix this error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type"

below is my code,

```
  enum Status {
      CANCELLED = 'cancelled',
      FAILED = 'failed',
  }

  const titleByStatus = {
      [Status.CANCELLED]: (name: string) => {
          return `${name} is cancelled`;
      },
      [Status.PASSED]: (name: string) => {
          return `${name} matches`;
      },
  };

  const getTitle = () => {
      if (result) {
          if (result.title && result.title !== '') {
              return result.title;
          } else {
              creturn titleByStatus[Status.CANCELLED](name) //error here
          }
       } else {
           return something[Status.CANCELLED];
       }
```

I have this getTitle being used in 2 places with result being different and Status.CANCELLED is replaced with something.status

so i am trying to rewrite reusable code like so

```
const getTitle = (result: any, status: someTypefromQuery, name: string) => {
      if (result) {
          if (result.title && result.title !== '') {
              return result.title;
          } else {
              return titleByStatus[status](name) //error here
          }
       } else {
           return something[status];
       }
   };
```

but i get error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type using typescript?

i call it like so in two places
const title = getTitle(result, Status.CANCELLED, name)
const title = getTitle(result, something.status, name)

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: This is not a minimal reproducible example. We are missing a lot of definitions. What is the `Status` enum?

Comment: yes Status is an enum

Comment: No, I'm asking for the definition. I know it's an enum. I don't know what the source is. When posting a question, ask yourself, "if I copy all the code in my post and paste it into a standalone IDE or playground, can I reproduce my problem?" If the answer is no, you are missing something. It also helps if you include a playground link yourself, so we don't have to waste time patching together the included snippets or making assumptions about what your code looks like.

Comment: It's still missing a lot of definitions: https://tsplay.dev/wXOGQW See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you are having trouble creating one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear what you're trying to achieve with the second function (result.title...so title is being tested to match the name of a given event in a status-specific context?)

at any rate, I think this should help

```
enum Status {
  CANCELLED = "cancelled",
  FAILED = "failed",
  PASSED = "passed"
}

const titleByStatus = {
  [Status.CANCELLED]: (name: string) => {
    return `${name} has been cancelled`;
  },
  [Status.PASSED]: (name: string) => {
    return `${name} matches (has passed)`;
  },
  [Status.FAILED]: (name: string) => {
    return `${name} has failed`;
  }
} as const;

const getTitle = (
  name: string,
  status: keyof typeof Status,
  result?: { title?: string }
) => {
  if (
    result?.title &&
    result?.title !== "" &&
    typeof result.title !== "undefined"
  ) {
    return result.title;
  } else {
    return status === "CANCELLED"
      ? titleByStatus[Status.CANCELLED](name)
      : status === "FAILED"
      ? titleByStatus[Status.FAILED](name)
      : titleByStatus[Status.PASSED](name);
  }
};

console.log(getTitle("test", "FAILED", {title: undefined}));
console.log(getTitle("test", "CANCELLED", {title: undefined}));
console.log(getTitle("test", "PASSED", {title: undefined}));
console.log(getTitle("test", "PASSED", {title: "I take priority when not undefined"}));
```

This outputs

```bash
[LOG]: "test has failed" 
[LOG]: "test has been cancelled" 
[LOG]: "test matches (has passed)" 
[LOG]: "I take priority when not undefined"
```

The index implicitly has an any type because of using an enum within an objects index without having the object fields defined as `readonly` which is what `as const` following the `titleByStatus` object definition achieves. There are 0 index errors now, you can check it out on the [typescript playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=39&pln=12&pc=43#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gWAFBSgYQEEA5fAUQBkKyARKAXigCIBjBEF4AGy%20ABMmAGhx4AYoQCS1OoyYAzBAEteA4bigAFQjBi0GzAA4IUKfkxwBfHDhYB7ECjhQ4iuLwBCAT3hJU%20rOoA2j7IKAB0RKSU0gC6AFxQABQgCBDACY4AToogAOYAlAwAfBgieFCZwMiZIFAABgAk6ClpFlAAFsZQAEbAoFBsHNwqdQDcZRZqeMGIoWFaOrTxSS3pUFk5BcWl6niV1bWNzanAbRBILO3AaImdaEYm-PljE1NQM77h4lJLCcknGTg2TyhXoJQC5QqVTANXqTVWbTuUAUyn4L3UVmwbS6dgccHG2Bs9kcUFyVQAKq5ePpEmVVoDgbk3o5PgkANbATy2OTOTwGYDc2CzVBvSooMBcOAAfgS6GcVOAMvWQM2UExoPBZUUPNpuyh4slUrCLjcwCgADJzWU9tcJdLjQqoABCeiyJgWq16uB8gU8sV2h2m52u5hgEB8YByHJmMqFCHlfYw2r%20yWB3gEvBtbimHaQxOwlmhBghpiRchUWjmPV4KXy01eEKoD5zMvRJb-NKFAD0ACpgJlMrZMh1%208Ae13reVAZ9i7JvtIq5Ca3WPN5hShm6gwvP26t8pO8AkTavGxvT-NtLoaDEO8B8hm1ZYCUSHLZeGEuLZcokyXBKabEiYOBrjgIRmB3GgwPQY81jDCMoxAfgLHye8XxQN9gA-L8fwpBVAOAxwwNLEhywXQQMBghI4MjaM%20GQ1DsFxdD30-b9f3-Xh8JAoiFivKDKKgaiEKQlCCSYjCsLY3CAKA7jyKYXjK3I6CFQSJgJGcBAOSgAxsiHVxPCgAB3K5ahAWwnCE2imHo0YgA)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this working code, comes from your example.

```js
export enum Status {
    CANCELLED = 'cancelled',
    FAILED = 'failed',
    PASSED = 'passed'
}

const titleByStatus = {
    [Status.CANCELLED]: (name: string) => {
        return `${name} is cancelled`;
    },
    [Status.PASSED]: (name: string) => {
        return `${name} matches`;
    },
};

const getTitle = (result: { title: string; }) => {
    if (result) {
        if (result.title && result.title !== '') {
            return result.title;
        } else {
            return titleByStatus[Status.CANCELLED]('name') //error here
        }
    } else {
        return titleByStatus[Status.CANCELLED];
    }
}
```